SQLAlchemy self-referenced Base with back_populates
I am attempting to develop a compact dictionary API and am encountering difficulties with the Database.
And describe base in this way (fields can be excluded if not needed).
translations = Table(
    "translations",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("left_id", ForeignKey("words.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_id", ForeignKey("words.id"), primary_key=True),
)

class Word(Base):
    __tablename__ = "words"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    value: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(24))
    translation: Mapped[Set["Word"]] = relationship(
        secondary=translations,
        primaryjoin=id == translations.c.left_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == translations.c.right_id,
        lazy="joined",
        back_populates="translation",
    )

My issue is that back_populates doesn't provide any automation.
""" Lets pretend session created here"""
w1 = Word(value="bonjour")
w2 = Word(value="hello")
s.add_all([w1, w2])
w1.translation.add(w2)
await s.commit()

And my w2.translation is empty set.
**Edited
Yes, it's named translation, but it involes many-to-many relationships. Now I aim to develop a technique that connects multiple words together.
Not having back references causes me to become overwhelmed by complexity, so it may not be a good decision:
def link(session, *args):
    for idx, word in enumerate(args[:-1]):
        word.translation.add(*[arg for arg in args if arg != word])
        # word.translation.add(*args[:idx], *[idx+1:])
    session.commit()





To make the relationship bi-directional, you'll need a 2nd relationship. An example is available in the docs.
class Word(Base):
    __tablename__ = "words"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    value: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(24))
    translation_to: Mapped[Set["Word"]] = relationship(
        "Word",
        secondary=translations,
        primaryjoin=id == translations.c.left_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == translations.c.right_id,
        back_populates="translation_from",
        lazy="joined",
    )
    translation_from: Mapped[Set["Word"]] = relationship(
        "Word",
        secondary=translations,
        primaryjoin=id == translations.c.right_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == translations.c.left_id,
        back_populates="translation_to",
        lazy="joined",
    )

back_populates now works as expected:
>>> w1 = Word(value="bonjour")
... w2 = Word(value="hello")
... w1.translation_to.add(w2)
>>> w2.translation_from
InstrumentedSet({<__main__.Word object at 0x0000022AEE9AD700>})

